# children of object

Tags: c#, uielementcollection

I have a function that is supposed to return a `UIElementCollection`. The function takes in a `UIElement` that has the `children` property (i.e. `stackpanel`, `grid`, etc.) but does not know which `UIElement` it is, so I store it into a general object.

```
public UIElementCollection retCol (object givenObject){
...
}
```

I want to return the children of the `givenObject`, but I can't find a way to do so besides casting `givenObject` as a stackpanel or grid.

Is there a way I can get the children property of the `givenObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StackPanel` and `Grid` both inherit from `Panel`, so you could change your method to:

```
public UIElementCollection retCol (Panel givenObject){
    return givenObject.Children;
}
```

Or if you want to make it available to ALL `UIElement` types you could make it more general and check the type in the function:

```
public UIElementCollection retCol (UIElement givenObject){
    if(givenObject is Panel)
        return ((Panel)givenObject).Children;
    else if(givenObject is SomeOtherContainer)
        return ((SomeOtherContainer)givenObject).Children;

    else
        return null;
}
```